# Why do i get Parser: The statement dialect could not be resolved due to ambiguity here?

Tags: ssas, ssms, mdx

I am trying to get two different topcounts on different rows, guess i am thinking wrong somewhere?

```
select{
([Measures].[Invoiced_DAm])
} on columns,

    topcount(
        [07 Prod].[Product_Descr].children
        ,10
        ,([Measures].[Invoiced_DAm], [19 Time].[Tr Year].&[2008])
    ),
    topcount(
        [07 Prod].[Product_Descr].children
        ,10
        ,([Measures].[Invoiced_DAm], [19 Time].[Tr Year].&[2009])
    ) on rows
```

Comment: Wrapping the 2 topcount between graphs { } would do the trick I think! I've just try a similar example on my test machine and it works!

Comment: I'm glad it's working now! if you want to know why you need graphs I'll explain it in an annswer!

Comment: that would be most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get it working is simply put TOPCOUNT operation between curly braces `{ }`:

```
select{
([Measures].[Invoiced_DAm])
} on columns,
{
    topcount(
        [07 Prod].[Product_Descr].children
        ,10
        ,([Measures].[Invoiced_DAm], [19 Time].[Tr Year].&[2008])
    ),
    topcount(
        [07 Prod].[Product_Descr].children
        ,10
        ,([Measures].[Invoiced_DAm], [19 Time].[Tr Year].&[2009])
    )
} on rows
```

Why? Beacuse it's the way that MDX distinguishes sets: we are required to surround tuples with braces anytime the tuples are explicitly listed. TOPCOUNT function will return (in this case) the top 10 tuples from Product dimension.

In your case `TOPCOUNT(...), TOPCOUNT(...)` means nothing to MDX (two sets, or list of tuples,  separate by comma).

`{TOPCOUNT(...), TOPCOUNT(...)}` will tell MDX that you want to display the set of rows coming from the two TOPCOUNT statement, so you declare a Set of sets, that is itself a set.